# How to iterate through cucumber test suite multiple times based on data from .csv file?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

I have this code so far to read data from a .csv file and put each row of information into a hash:

```
require 'csv'

module DataParser

  @test_data = {}

  CSV.foreach("C:/Documents and Settings/a676200/Desktop/config.csv") do |row|
      test_case, first_name, last_name, ssn = row
      next if test_case == "Test Case"
      @test_data[test_case] = {
        :first_name             => first_name,
        :last_name              => last_name,
        :ssn                    => ssn,
      }
  end

  def self.test_data(test_case = 0)
    @test_data[test_case] || @test_data
  end

end
```

I have a typical cucumber structure with my steps defined using watir-webdriver. My question is how can I get this code to iterate through my cucumber features X number of times, using the data from each row for a single test run? So, if there were 3 rows of data, I want my cucumber test suite to execute 3 times with the different data.

Currently I have this file located in my support folder, but I'm struggling on how to make it iterate from within the project structure. Does this need to be pulled out of the project and executed first, then call the cucumber execution while passing in these values at runtime?